# Packaging a document with Indesign SDK

Tags: sdk, adobe-indesign

I would like to package an indesign document through the SDK but there doesnt seem to be any documentation about it. Does anyone know if it is possible, and if so, help me on the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out these articles, I think they may be helpful:

[Packaging Adobe InDesign Files for Press](http://kevin-randall.hubpages.com/hub/Packaging-Adobe-InDesign-Files-for-Press)

[Packaging ID Files](http://www.gomediazine.com/tutorials/tools-tips/preparing-indesign-files-for-your-print-service/)

If not, maybe elaborate your question a little further? Good luck!