# Package indesign document with SDK c++

Tags: c++, sdk, adobe-indesign

I would like to package an indesign document through the SDK (c++ or javascript, it doesn't matter) but I cannot find any documentation.

Does anyone know if it is possible?

This is the duplication of the question [Packaging a document with Indesign SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583393/packaging-a-document-with-indesign-sdk) that was marked as answered but the accepted answer describes how to package via UI and NOT via SDK.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with JavaScript. All you need to do is call the [`packageForPrint` method](http://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#Document.html#d1e47790__d1e50712) of InDesign's document object and use a whole lot of booleans to set the options (see the linked doc page for details).